# How can we achive tabbarcontroller like functionlity using UIbutton?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipod

I wanted two switched between two three view controller by preserving there current context exactly like what the TabBarController does. But without using TabBarController template.

See the attache screen shot.

?[image]

Comment: please use custom tab bar controller

Answer (score 2):

If you've been working on same `UIView`, you can do something like

Take a `UISegmentedControl` and three `UIViews` in your `.h` file.

Buind each view and, segment control with `changeView` action in `IB` for  `UIControlEventsValueChanged`

```
- (IBAction) changeView
{    
 switch (segmentViews.selectedSegmentIndex) 
 {
    case 0:
        [firstView setHidden:NO];
        [secondView setHidden:YES];
        [thirdView setHidden:YES];
        break;

    case 1:
        [firstView setHidden:YES];  
        [secondView setHidden:NO];
        [thirdView setHidden:YES];
        break;

    case 2:
        [firstView setHidden:YES];
        [secondView setHidden:YES];
        [thirdView setHidden:NO];
        break;
 }
}
```

It will change with the change of `selectedSegmentIndex` gets changed. Give proper `backgrondColor`it will look like `tapbar`. You can even add `animation` for view transition effects.

It can be works well with different `UIViewControllers`, but you've to add `UISegmentControl` and maintain `UIDesign` in each controller. Also need to maintain `currentIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

In your VC you should define 3 `UIViewController` and initialize them in the `-(id)init` method. Then when you press a button you only attach the corresponding view controller on `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one "master" view controller, and have it put the control at the bottom of its view. Then it would "present" and "dismiss" the 3 view controllers as the buttons are pushed (I hope that's a segmented control you are showing). This should all work nicely just using the standard features of UIViewController.

EDIT: To deal with the transition, you will need to play with various ideas to find the one you like best. Some ideas:

- when a different tab is tapped, dismiss the view showing and present the new view with no animation. This should mimic what the tabBarController does
- read the paragraph in UIViewController class description titled 'Implementing a Container View Controller' - it shows you the various ways container views can cause a transition from viewController A to viewController B

Comment: but tab tab do not work like this. It preserve the contain(like variable, view added on it etc) of the previous view and show to us when we come back on it. Dismissing controller leads to start from beginning again for that view.

Answer (score 0):

In your Code you should define 3 UIViewController and you can set hidden property of remain two views on pressing any one view. Then when you press any other button you then you can show  hidden property and set hidden property for previous view.